# Google Maps API Chinese file missing

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm loading the Google Maps API, and the Chinese localized version doesn't seem to want to load. The main js file loaded by the Google bootstrapper looks like this:

```
window.google = window.google || {};
google.maps = google.maps || {};
(function() {

  function getScript(src) {
    document.write('<' + 'script src="' + src + '"' +
                   ' type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>');
  }

  var modules = google.maps.modules = {};
  google.maps.__gjsload__ = function(name, text) {
    modules[name] = text;
  };

  google.maps.Load = function(apiLoad) {
    delete google.maps.Load;
    apiLoad([0.009999999776482582,[[["http://mt0.google.cn/vt?lyrs=m@160000000\u0026hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026","http://mt1.google.cn/vt?lyrs=m@160000000\u0026hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"m@216000000"],[["http://mt0.google.cn/vt?lyrs=s@128\u0026hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026","http://mt1.google.cn/vt?lyrs=s@128\u0026hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026"],null,null,null,1,"128"],[["http://mt0.google.cn/vt?imgtp=png32\u0026lyrs=h@160000000\u0026hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026","http://mt1.google.cn/vt?imgtp=png32\u0026lyrs=h@160000000\u0026hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026"],null,null,"imgtp=png32\u0026",null,"h@216000000"],[["http://mt0.google.cn/vt?lyrs=t@127,r@160000000\u0026hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026","http://mt1.google.cn/vt?lyrs=t@127,r@160000000\u0026hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"t@131,r@216000000"],null,null,[["http://cbk0.googleapis.com/cbk?","http://cbk1.googleapis.com/cbk?"]],[["http://khm0.googleapis.com/kh?v=75\u0026hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026","http://khm1.googleapis.com/kh?v=75\u0026hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"75"],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026"]],[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt/loom?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026","http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt/loom?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=zh-CN\u0026gl=CN\u0026"]]],["zh-CN","CN",null,0,null,null,"http://maps.gstatic.cn/mapfiles/","http://csi.gstatic.com","https://maps.googleapis.com","http://maps.googleapis.com"],["http://maps.gstatic.cn/intl/zh_cn/mapfiles/api-3/12/11","3.12.11"],[2093058546],1.0,null,null,null,null,0,"",null,null,0,"http://khm.googleapis.com/mz?v=128\u0026",null,"https://earthbuilder.googleapis.com","https://earthbuilder.googleapis.com",null,"http://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon"], loadScriptTime);
  };
  var loadScriptTime = (new Date).getTime();
  getScript("http://maps.gstatic.cn/intl/zh_cn/mapfiles/api-3/12/11/main.js");
})();
```

You can see the getScript is trying to call `http://maps.gstatic.cn/intl/zh_cn/mapfiles/api-3/12/11/main.js` -- but this script doesn't seem to exist.

I noticed this for the first time today-- is this a temporary server error on Google's part? Or is my code out of date or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took way longer than I would have guessed for Google to sort this out, but apparently it was either a DNS or server issue, since the file is now back and displays correctly.

Comment: turns out for some reason when setting the `region` option in the API loader URL it causes some weird issues of missing / blocked files. Once we edited to remove the `region` setting, it all worked as expected.